# Proving associativity of $A\oplus B = (A \cup B)-(A \cap B)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-set-theory

I'm trying to prove that the binary operation $\oplus$ defined by $A\oplus B=(A\cup B)-(A\cap B)$ is associative, but I'm getting tripped up on the algebra and I feel like there must be a different way. Of course, I started by asserting that we want to show that $A\oplus (B\oplus C) = (A\oplus B) \oplus C$. From there, I have the following:

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
(A\oplus B)\oplus C &= ((A\cup B) - (A\cap B))\oplus C \\
&= (((A\cup B) - (A\cap B))\cup C) - (((A\cup B) - (A\cap B)\cap C)\\
&= ((A-B)\cup(B-A)\cup C) - (((A-B)\cup (B-A)) \cap C)\\
&= ???...\\
&= (A\cup ((B\cup C)-(B \cap C)))-(A\cap ((B\cup C)-(B\cap C)))
\end{split}
\end{equation}

I just can't figure out how to get rid of the minuses and get A alone. I've drawn some Venn Diagrams but I still don't see it.

Comment: Try this definition for symmetric difference: $A\oplus B=(A\cap B^c)\cup(A^c\cap B)$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: 
$$A-B=A\cap B^c$$
That is it is the intersection with the latter sets complement.

Comment: Ah yes I managed to forget about this. Does the complement "distribute" and flip union to intersection and vice versa?

Comment: Yes $(A\cup B)^c=A^c\cap B^c$,

Answer (score 1):

Alternative:

Verify that: $$1_{A\oplus B}=1_{A}+1_{B}-21_{A}1_{B}$$

Then: $$1_{\left(A\oplus B\right)\oplus C}=\left[1_{A}+1_{B}-21_{A}1_{B}\right]+1_{C}-2\left[1_{A}+1_{B}-21_{A}1_{B}\right]1_{C}=$$$$1_{A}+1_{B}+1_{C}-2\left[1_{A}1_{B}+1_{A}1_{C}+1_{B}1_{C}\right]+41_{A}1_{B}1_{C}$$
Working out $1_{A\oplus\left(B\oplus C\right)}$ leads to the same expression.